# How to trace the code which is being executed in chromium when a web page is running on Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, chromium

I'm exploring Chromium source code, I want to find out what code internally triggers whenever I render a web page on chromium browser. Any sources on how do I do that?

I tried going through this

https://slack.engineering/chrome-tracing-for-fun-and-profit/

and

https://nolanlawson.com/2022/10/26/a-beginners-guide-to-chrome-tracing/

But it didn't help much

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with the Chromium source code and architecture then you will know which repo is responsible for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Asesh chromium is too big for doing source code exploration, any other ways i could debug and try to find stack trace. I have found this https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/45287.pdf interesting but you know how do I apply to chromium?

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful to you: https://www.chromium.org/blink/getting-started-with-blink-debugging/